# Qt framebuffer app doesn't start on Raspberry (BUILDROOT)

Tags: qt, embedded, raspberry-pi3, framebuffer, buildroot

i'm building my personal embedded OS that execute a gui at startup in less than 4 seconds.
I didn't installed X.org platform because Qt can run over linuxfb without a Desktop Environment.
If i launch my PyQt application or the native analogclock example from terminal all works fine. But if i insert the command to launch these applications in /etc/inittab, they don't start until i insert some input device, such as keyboard mouse, or USB.
It's a very strange situation and i really hope that you can tell me what i'm wrong.
Thank you,
Alberto

Comment: I'm not sure if the root of the problem is the same but I wasn't able to run my pyqt5 app on startup too. Then I noticed that even if I set QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb and run another script which eventually would run my app, QT wouldn't run on linuxfb. So I moved my "export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb" right before "python main.py" and it worked. Still don't know what causes this bug like problem but this workaround works for now.

Comment: In your case, it seems like a slightly different problem, you could try to run your app with export QT_LOGGING_RULES="*=true" and maybe get some insight on whats going on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where should i insert it?

Comment: right before you start your app in /etc/inittab

Comment: @AlbertoMercurio. Did you found a way for this finally?